# Restart Django Application, Deployed on IIS with FastCGI

Tags: django, iis, fastcgi

I've successfully setup Django on IIS with FastCGI, the problem is how to restart Django application after views.py update. I've tried restarting the IIS site and application pool and `IISReset` command; that does not make any change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find better solution by specifying `monitorChangesTo` parameter in FastCGI according to following document on views.py. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Clear browser history and cache then try to access the site again.

or you could use django-livereload-server

This django app adds a management command that starts a livereload server watching all your static files and templates as well as a custom runserver command that issues livereload requests when the development server is ready after a restart.

```
$ pip install django-livereload-server
```

Add `'livereload.middleware.LiveReloadScript'` to `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` in settings.py.

Then run

```
$ ./manage.py livereload
```

before starting the server.

https://github.com/tjwalch/django-livereload-server

Comment: Clearing browser history and cache is irritated for sure, because it is on server-side as it has no static file (rest api). I will Check Livereload and Report result, Thanks.